# Importing module to use partially in other modules

Tags: angular

I realized that most of the code examples imports material modules component in one  module and import it everywhere to use, like below;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

But imagine that i want to use MatMenuModule only in one module and other module may not needed it, or 3. module may not needed both the components that first and second needed, whats the best practice to use material or another shared modules elements partially in other modules and why not import and export material module inside app module instead of import everywhere?

Comment: You can import the material modules individually into one of your modules if you're worried about unused material modules. For me, it's easier to import the MaterialModule like you're doing here. Haven't run the benchmarks though.

Comment: and @francojay what about to just import & export it via app module only means other child modules can access and use it without importing again.

Comment: Yes, In that case, I would recommend importing the MaterialModule into AppModule. It’s important to keep things as modular as possible. If grouping them has no performance issues, it’s cleaner and easier to globally add a module.

Answer (score 0):

I see that most of the people create a separate module say `material.module.ts` and include all the Mat Modules in this file and import this Module in the module that they need.

This way, the code looks neater but is not effective in terms of size of the app

I prefer to import only the Mat modules that I need for a particular module.

Comment: are you sure about performance issues i can not remember where i read but they were indicating importing modules has no performance issues.

Comment: When you do a production build `ng build --prod`, the unused modules are removed using the tree-shaking. So they don't end up in the final code hence no performance issues